# C# .Net Core API Authorized route with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an API which is using Identity Server 4 and register and login routes work. But the ones which I protect with `[Authorized]` give me `404` with or without Authorization header. If I remove `[Authorized]` from route, it get's hit right. What might be the problem?

This is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Security.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAccountService accountService;

        public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
        {
            this.accountService = accountService;
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "You are seeing this because account controller is working fine!";
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("getauthorized")]
        public string GetAuthorized()
        {
            return "This is authorized okay.";
        }
...
```

First route get's hit, second one doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put the [Authorize] attribute on the Relying party, means your web app which is calling the web apis. Identity server secure your web apis by token authentication.

- Put [Authorize] on the client app (RP)
- It will be redirected to auth server login/register
- After successful login, will be redirected to client app
- here get the access token and call your api

Comment: Well it should be like that in the future, but this was for testing purposes. Shouldn't the route be hit anyway? I mean, the route doesn't know whether it is a client or server, it listens to the request I specify :)

Comment: actually it kinda does know as we have to configure the middleware differently if its a client or web api